# Can traditional neural networks be combined with spiking neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, spiking-neural-networks

Can traditional neural networks be combined with spiking neural networks? And can there be training algorithms for such hybrid network? Does such hybrid network model biological brains?

As I understand, brains contain only spiking networks and traditional networks are more or less crude approximation of them. But we can imagine that evolutionary computing can surpass the biological evolution and so the new structure can be created that are better than mind. And that is why the question about such tradition-spiking hybrid neural networks should be interesting.